# JQuery On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can' quite figure out how to properly attach a jquery function to a div. For now, I just want to be able to click the div, and have the jquery pop up and tell me it was clicked. As of now, nothing happens when I click the div.

```
<div id="yahoologin" name="yahoologin">
    <input type="submit" value="" name="submit" />
</div>
```

My jquery is in a separate file:

```
$('#yahoologin').on('click',(function() {
    alert("YOU CLICKED IT!");
});
```

Does my jquery need to be in the same file?

WHen I run this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert("HI");
});
```

It works, so I know I'm linking to the right page.

Comment: run it with a debug console. the error will be pointed out in red.

Comment: the quickest way to find out if there is any syntax issues is to run your code in http://jsfiffle.net and the just click js hint this indicates errors if any

Comment: The **quickest way** is to use a debug console. To open the console in Chrome, hit f12 and select Console from the tabs. It's very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

click function should be inside ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#yahoologin').on('click',(function() {
        alert("YOU CLICKED IT!");
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra `(` here right before `function`

```
$('#yahoologin').on('click',(function() {
                            ^
    alert("YOU CLICKED IT!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The ( before function is what causes the error. Whas's more, you can simply use:

```
$('#yahoologin').click(function() {
                        ^
    alert("YOU CLICKED IT!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your selector is executing before document ready event, try this:
Note: I've removed a typo in your handler declaration.

```
$(function(){
     $('#yahoologin').on('click',function() {
         alert("YOU CLICKED IT!");
     });
});
```